# Reset a group of identifiers to a sequence of consecutive serial numbers in a Pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nlp

I have generated three outputs from a dataframe and I am trying to reset the identifiers of my sentences (`Sentence_ID`) by starting from 1 for each output.

Output exemple :

```
Sentence_ID  Mention Tag
6388    Chailland   B-LOCATION
6388    ,   O
6388    Mayenne B-LOCATION

6389    poste   O
6389    de  O
6389    Goumois B-LOCATION
6389    (   I-LOCATION
6389    Doubs   I-LOCATION
6389    )   I-LOCATION
6389    .   O
        
6390    Pichet  B-PERSON
6390    (   O
6390    veuve   O
6390    )   O
6390    ,   O
6390    de  O
6390    Paris   B-LOCATION
6390    .   O
... continue
```

Expected Output :

```
Sentence_ID  Mention Tag
1 Chailland B-LOCATION
1   ,   O
1   Mayenne B-LOCATION

2   poste   O
2   de  O
2   Goumois B-LOCATION
2   (   I-LOCATION
2   Doubs   I-LOCATION
2   )   I-LOCATION
2   .   O
        
3   Pichet  B-PERSON
3   (   O
3   veuve   O
3   )   O
3   ,   O
3   de  O
3   Paris   B-LOCATION
3   .   O
... continue
```

I must be missing something, but not sure if I should apply a counter on `Sentence_id` column (via `group_by()`) or `reset_index` on this specific columns to complete this task.

If anyone has a lead, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) to generate a new set of sequence numbers, as follows:

```
df['Sentence_ID'] = pd.factorize(df['Sentence_ID'])[0] + 1
```

or use [`Series.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.factorize.html)

```
df['Sentence_ID'] = df['Sentence_ID'].factorize()[0] + 1
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)


    Sentence_ID    Mention         Tag
0             1  Chailland  B-LOCATION
1             1          ,           O
2             1    Mayenne  B-LOCATION
3             2      poste           O
4             2         de           O
5             2    Goumois  B-LOCATION
6             2          (  I-LOCATION
7             2      Doubs  I-LOCATION
8             2          )  I-LOCATION
9             2          .           O
10            3     Pichet    B-PERSON
11            3          (           O
12            3      veuve           O
13            3          )           O
14            3          ,           O
15            3         de           O
16            3      Paris  B-LOCATION
17            3          .           O
```

Comment: it works perfectly! thank you. I didn't understand at the beginning why I lost the whitespaces between the sentences but after tests it works.

Comment: @Lter  This solution just affect the `Sentence_ID` column.  Maybe I have used your sample data as 3 columns instead of 2 columns with the second column with whitespace.  Anyway, it's just for demo purposes. Other columns won't be affected.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary whose keys are old IDs and values are new IDs, and use it to map a new `Sentence_ID` column

```
mapping = dict(zip(df["Sentence_ID"].unique(), range(1, df["Sentence_ID"].nunique() +1)))
df["Sentence_ID"] = df["Sentence_ID"].map(mapping)
```